# What is the probability you know at least one person with a disease that occurs in 4% of people?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I am writing a paper for psychology in school on bipolar disorder and one of my hypothesis was that most people don't know anyone with this disease, but the data from my survey indicates that actually 51% of people know someone with this disorder.

I would like to back this up with a calculation of actual probability that a random person knows someone with that disease. I have tried to look for some studies on the internet but wasn't able to find anything, if you find anything please let me know. Otherwise, I would appreciate if you can do some probabilistic estimate, which I don't know how to, since there are too many variables. I would also like to mention that in my study not knowing someone means knowing 0 people with it and knowing someone with it means at least 1 person with it. The probability that a random person has this disorder is 4%, according to my sources.

Thank you,

Matthew

Comment: Caution: the people you know are not a random sample from the population.  There are many plausible reasons why your acquaintances might be more or less likely to have the disease than the general population.

Comment: To be clear:  the probabilistic computation will give a number which is effectively $100\%$.  Even if you know only $100$ people the answer would be $1-.96^{100}\approx .98$.  Nothing at all like your $51\%$.  Questions of independence and reporting bias loom very large.

Comment: To stress:  to justify the $51\%$, under a (perhaps unphysical) assumption of independence, you'd need for everyone to know only about $24.5$ people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you know $n$ people. If the first person has the disease, you already know at least one person with the disease. The probability of that happening is $4$%. If the first person does not have the disease but the second person does, you're done as well. The probability is $96$% times $4$% (i.e. $0.96\cdot 0.04$), and so on. All in all, the probability that you know at least one person with the disease will be $0.04\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 0.96^n = 0.04\frac{1-0.96^{n}}{0.04} = 1-0.96^{n}$.

Comment: You should have $1-0.96^n$, which you can also get by an easier argument: for each of the $n$ acquaintances the probability of not having the disease is $0.96$, so the probability that none has it is $0.96^n$, and the probability that at least one has it is $1-0.96^n$. You could also include some numerical data: for $n=100$ the probability is about $0.983$, and for $n=50$ it’s about $0.870$ — in both cases pretty substantial.

Comment: But how is it possible then that half the people don't know anyone bipolar if  1-(0,96^600)=0,9999... -> my calculator just rounds on 1. (https://www.nytimes.com/2013/02/19/science/the-average-american-knows-how-many-people.html).  Is it that they don't know these people well enough to know that they actually have bipolar disorder?

Comment: @Matthew That could be part of it. Do you know the psychiatric histories of all of your acquaintances?  People with bipolar disorder usually don't go around advertising that fact.  They may not even know it themselves.

Comment: ... Also, people might be forgetting the fact that some acquaintance is bipolar when they fill out your survey.  Or they might think it's none of your business.

Comment: Yes, I think so too now. Most people you know won't tell you about it, so it is completely pointless to look at all the people you know - it would be better to look at friends - an average person has 150 casual friends: https://www.goodtherapy.org/blog/psychology-facts/how-many-friends-does-average-person-have-0208197 .  And also, not all of them know they have it. I now checked my data, and 4% is an estimated number, only 2.6% are actually diagnosed - so many don't even know. Considering that even casual friend might not tell you, the probability is less than 98% - much more reasonable.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The survey was anonymous so I think they wouldn't think it's none of my business, but yes, they might forget that they know someone with it. Thanks for your help! I will add those concerns in my analysis and I think it will be okay if I explain why the results might be off.